# Cross origin request (COR) with embedded jetty

Tags: jetty, cross-domain, embedded-jetty, cesiumjs

I have a KML Server that outputs KML data and that I can configure as network place in Google Earth. The KML Server uses embedded Jetty.

I would like to also run the KML Server under Cecium, but then I need to configure Jetty to allow COR. Cesium runs from a webbowser.

There are many example w.r.t. Jettty/COR, but many of them do not run, are outdated, and are just unclear.

The KML Server main program is:

```
    /*
    ** Create HHTP server
     */
    final Server server = new Server(config.getKmlPortNumber());

    // Set a handler for each context
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    Handler[] contextHandler = new Handler[ForceIdentifier.TOTAL_IDENTIFIERS + 1];

    final ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler("/");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setHandler(new DefaultHandler(env));
    contextHandler[0] = context;

    // Set a handler for each Force Identifier.
    for (byte i = 0; i < ForceIdentifier.TOTAL_IDENTIFIERS; i++) {
        ContextHandler contexti = new ContextHandler("/" + i);

        contexti.setHandler(new DefaultHandler(env, new ForceIdentifier(i)));
        contextHandler[i + 1] = contexti;
    }

    contexts.setHandlers(contextHandler);
    server.setHandler(contexts);

    // Start the server and set some options
    server.start();
    //server.dumpStdErr();
    server.setStopTimeout(1000);
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

    /*
    ** Start the federate
     */
    try {
        federate.start();
    } catch (RTIexception ex) {
        Main.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    /*
    ** Stop the federate
     */
    federate.stop();
```

The KML Server uses serveral context handlers.

What needs to be done to enable COR here?

(Jetty version is: jetty-all-9.2.10.v20150310)

Comment: Jetty's [DefaultHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/DefaultHandler.html) does not have a constructor with an argument.  What version of Jetty are you using?? (not Jetty 9.2.10.v20150310, that's for sure).   Also [don't use jetty-all.jar it does not contain all of jetty, nor can it, its only meant for quick-start & documentation use](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).

Answer (score 1):

[`org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CrossOriginFilter.html) the technique that Jetty has for enabling COR related features, is only available under a `ServletContext`, meaning your example code, which doesn't use `Servlets`, or a `ServletContext` cannot utilize this filter.

You can, however, make your own `Handler` to do the COR related work for your servlet-free environment.  (Consider looking at the [cougar project](https://github.com/betfair/cougar), and its [`CrossOriginHandler`](https://github.com/betfair/cougar/blob/master/cougar-framework/jetty-transport/src/main/java/com/betfair/cougar/transport/jetty/CrossOriginHandler.java) implementation for inspiration)

Or you can switch to using a `ServletContextHandler` instead of a `ContextHandler` and then gain the benefit of using Jetty `CrossOriginFilter` in your project.